# Exception handler not raising

Tags: exception, plsql, handler

**UPDATE fixed the errors shown but its still not functioning as I would like it to. I need to create a user defined exception handler that does not allow null values to be inserted as the item cost but for some reason raise missing_cost is not running. I set the item_id and item_cost to be user defined but I think its not passing correctly?

tables are:

```
pitem
{item_id number;
 item_name char(20);
 item_desc char(20);
 retail_price number(10,2);
 item_cost number(10,2);
 category char(10);
}
```

and...

```
pitem_audit
{item_id number;
message char(80);
}
```

thanks in advance!

```
create or replace procedure update_item_cost (iItemId INTEGER, 
fNewcost NUMBER) as fCurCost NUMBER(10,2);
missing_cost EXCEPTION;

item_id pitem.item_id%type :=&item_id;
item_cost pitem.item_cost%type := &item_cost;


begin
    select item_cost into fCurCost from pitem
    where item_id=iItemid;

    if fCurCost IS null then
        raise missing_cost;
    else
        update pitem set item_cost=fNewCost
        where item_id=iItemid;
    end if;

commit;
end;

exception
    when no_data_found then
    insert into pitem_audit
        values(iItemid, 'Invalid Item identifier.');
    commit;
    when missing_cost then
    insert into pitem_audit
        values(iItemid, 'Item Cost is null.');
    commit;
    when others then
    rollback;
    insert into pitem_audit
        values(iItemid, 'Miscellaneous error.');
    commit;
end update_item_cost;
/
```

Comment: In Oracle SqlPlus or studio you can put `show errors` after create statement. It will tell you the error. Not sure what DB you use but it probably has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of a procedure:

```
procedure <procname>
   (<parameters>)
as
   <declarations>
begin
   <body to execute>
exception
   <exception handlers>
end <procname>;
```

In your case, you have an extra `end;`:

```
procedure <procname>
   (<parameters>)
as
   <declarations>
begin
   <body to execute>
end; <-- this is incorrect
exception
   <exception handlers>
end <procname>;
```

Comment: im stupid i was missing something in my code...figured it out thanks